# How do I use sorl-thumbnail? (django)

Tags: python, django, django-models, thumbnails, sorl-thumbnail

I've been looking at the sorl-thumbnail's documentation, and I still can't figure out how to:

1. upload images to sorl-thumbnail.
2. selectively show images from sorl-thumbnail.
   (for example, load a specific image from sorl-thumbnail from a view and show it, with customized size, etc.)

Could you give some specific examples on how to use this library in a django view?

Answer (score 12):

If you want greater flexibility you can generate the thumbnail right in the view. The following is straight from the [sorl-thumbnail documentation](http://sorl-thumbnail.readthedocs.org/en/latest/examples.html#low-level-api-examples):

```
from sorl.thumbnail import get_thumbnail

im = get_thumbnail(my_file, '100x100', crop='center', quality=99)
```

`im` then is the same thing as what you'd get back from the `thumbnail` template tag. So, you can add that variable to the template context, or just some part of it. For example if you just wanted the URL:

```
my_context = {
    'image_url': im.url,
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use sorl.thumbnail using the thumbnail template tags. Here's an example:

```
{% load thumbnail %}

{% thumbnail recipe.image "430x250" as thumb %}
     <img src="{{ thumb.url }}" width="{{ thumb.width }}" height="{{ thumb.height }}" alt="{{ recipe.title }}" />
{% endthumbnail %}
```

You don't upload images to sorl.thumbnail or load them from sorl.thumbnail. After proper configuration it will resize and store the images automatically and you can use the `thumbnail` template tag to get the proper URL of the image.

Comment: Thanks for the reply :D btw, is there no way I can selectively show images from the DB using sorl-thumb? Also, can you give me some example django view part? (not only the template part) Thanks again

Comment: The view has no code for thumbnails (unless you want to). In the above example it's an image of a Recipe model. You can pass a variable in view to the template if you want to (e.g., `image = ...` and then replace `recipe.image` by `image`).

Comment: Just to make it clear, since i am also trying to understand it. 

Sorl does not save images in database, instead it has it's own filesystem storage?

Essentially i only have to upload one size image, and then just request whatever size i want, in which case sorl will either generate that image on the fly or fetch it if it was generated previously from it's own storage?

Answer (score 1):

When I have to use sorl-thumbnail I make difference between 2 kind of images:

## **Django objects with ImageField**

When I have an object in Django with an ImageField I render it with thumbnail like this:

```
# Let's supose our object imagefield is called img
{% thumbnail obj.img "100" upscale=false as im %}
   <img src="{{ im.url }}"/>
{% empty %}  # In case the object doesn't have an image, use generic one
   {% thumbnail "img/empty_img.jpg" "236" upscale=false as im %}
        <img src="{{ im.url }}" />
   {% endthumbnail %}
{% endthumbnail %}
```

---

## **Images by url/path**

To load images using **local path** of the project:

```
{% thumbnail "img/myImage.jpg" "236" upscale=false as im %}
    <img src="{{ im.url }}" />
{% endthumbnail %}
```

**Important:** Remember that thumbnail concatenates the **MEDIA_URL** to the path you provide, so in this case you need a path like **`yourapp/media/img/myImage.jpg`**

To load images using an **URL** is easy and sample:

```
{% thumbnail "http://www.nextgen-gallery.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/12/abend.jpg" "236" upscale=false as im %}
    <img src="{{ im.url }}" />
{% endthumbnail %}
```